# Is it safe to set git's core.precomposeunicode = true globally?

Tags: git

We're setting up `git 1.8` in a mixed environment (OSX, Linux, Windows) and there are filenames that use non-English characters. I've read that that `core.precomposeunicode` needs to be set to `true` on the OSX systems.

We're not concerned with backward compatibility. We *are* concerned with keeping things simple for the developers. We'd rather not have to explain about `git` configuration.

So: is it safe to set that flag globally (in the central git server)? Will that enforce the consistency we need? Is there a reason not to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that won't work. There is no such thing as a central git server in a *distributed* version control system - at least not in the technical sense.

Each developer has his own repository to which he checks in his changes. When those changes are pushed to the repository you *declare* as central, the data is not re-processed.

You will have to set that configuration on every local repository.
Unfortunately, there is no alternative with .gitattributes either.

Local options for a certain repository that will then be cloned by the developers isn't an option either. The following simple experiment shows this:

```
d:\Temp\Origin>git init
Initialized empty Git repository in d:/Temp/Origin/.git/

d:\Temp\Origin>git config --local --add core.autocrlf input
d:\Temp\Origin>git config --local --list
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
core.autocrlf=input
d:\Temp\Origin>cd ..
d:\Temp>git clone d:\Temp\Origin Developer
Cloning into 'Developer'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
done.

d:\Temp>cd Developer

d:\Temp\Developer>git config --local --list
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
remote.origin.url=d:\Temp\Origin
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Note how the call to `git config --local --list` in `Origin` lists `core.autocrlf=input` and the same command in `Developer` doesn't, although we just cloned `Developer` from `Origin`.
That demonstrates that repository-local configuration values are *not* cloned.

Comment: What I've been told is we want to "set the variable on the server so that it is inherited by the users" - are you saying this isn't how it works? (I can't find a clear explanation in the git docs, but probably I don't know what to ask for.)

Comment: @egrunin: As I said: Technically, there simply *is no* central server. All repositories are technically on the same level. You can set a configuration option only for a specific repository. But that option will not be "transmitted" when you clone it.

Comment: +1 This is very helpful. I'm going to show this to the team and make sure I've represented our question properly.

Comment: We're still arguing over here, but I'm giving you the thumbs up anyway - thanks for the in-depth answer!

Comment: @egrunin: You are welcome :) Working with git sometimes requires a bit of discipline from all involved. One idea though: You could create a script that creates the initial clone and sets the correct local configuration.

Answer (score 1):

While repository-local configuration values are not cloned, Git 2.37 (Q3 2022), will be more robust regarding `core.precomposeunicode` on Mac, for the [**fsmonitor**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66927367/6309) (a [daemon watching the working directory](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsmonitor--daemon) for file and directory changes using platform-specific file system notification facilities,  communicating directly with commands like `git status`).

That way, setting `core.precomposeunicode` to `true` is better managed.

See [commit 3294ca6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3294ca6140875163b538eab08b56d1c8b3ccca5b), [commit 53fcfbc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/53fcfbc84f68d11c9635fe58f72ce5a83200e051), [commit eb29901](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb299010eee63b5a069d82836efb38969ffd4109), [commit 00991e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/00991e1013750130bbe4b4ac81279d6997935236), [commit 9915e08](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9915e08f9bc4122a1d49101fff43be20a2ea6cb5), [commit d6d58ff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6d58ff8abd382226980f00360e12e4bf91456e4), [commit caa9c37](https://github.com/git/git/commit/caa9c37ec0b1c30ac1df266d01da6edb2c49d8ad), [commit f954c7b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f954c7b8ff3f1443dfd52b5d0c59208a8d1d87ec), [commit 7667f9d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7667f9d2ae944dbea85aeda7093af5c87904245c), [commit b533708](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5337082b34dbdb25f27014518841a6f78d82bf6), [commit 95a4e78](https://github.com/git/git/commit/95a4e78a746be2b87972c03c82e8b1fe8fe0bea1), [commit de7e0b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de7e0b58ea4bb1ca8242e677096dae50f96e9b7e), [commit 6504cfd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6504cfd392936f6e3994216101659fcda24ed1ac), [commit 90a70fa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/90a70fa80964e7d582fb8df2c0115da79d13f5ab), [commit d060555](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d06055501b0d31c417f8cbd237efb48065256d83), [commit 207534e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/207534e423d95861c27444d4cf9760bf16edc6c8), [commit 802aa31](https://github.com/git/git/commit/802aa31840bd2080f668d0efbaeea2021f4e2488), [commit 39664e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/39664e93093bd9545ad4085523b122196c449508), [commit 8e8f4b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e8f4b814bab3f1499e50404e344f5b483c91f40), [commit 9968ed7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9968ed73ff8bf00d06862e6653451faeb008afef), [commit ddc5dac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ddc5dacfb368d4903f5dd475897e5e11772f9970), [commit d989b26](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d989b266c1a7ef47f27cec75e90f3dfefbfa0200), [commit 1e7be10](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e7be10de0d493f471bf102a7eed32da8247c825), [commit a85ad67](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a85ad67bbdadb24ddb9b58a4010e20105c4c25e9), [commit 5c58fbd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c58fbd26579391d825cb1ef0df8703bd6fd0ed5), [commit d33c804](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d33c804daec8aaf1e8af187c00166ef4cb017262), [commit 62a62a2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/62a62a28308453ee830bb7e02cf732474a6e01a5), [commit 49b398a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49b398a970f6efa368114330da23ae69aeeb9c60), [commit 27b5d41](https://github.com/git/git/commit/27b5d4171d90073e37c7c1233b6bcc95ba58ae1d), [commit 40f865d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/40f865dc025cfb91ee6338f688c06cdc65b53fa0) (26 May 2022) by [Jeff Hostetler (`Jeff-Hostetler`)](https://github.com/Jeff-Hostetler).
See [commit 852e2c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/852e2c84f847d99e29fd08feb8cea881dca63c79) (25 Mar 2022) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9e496ff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e496fffc872b20a147d7b80330335edfff919cc), 10 Jun 2022)</sup>

> ### [`fsmonitor`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6d58ff8abd382226980f00360e12e4bf91456e4): on macOS also emit NFC spelling for NFD pathname
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff Hostetler</sup>

> Emit NFC or NFC and NFD spellings of pathnames on macOS.
>
> MacOS is Unicode composition insensitive, so NFC and NFD spellings are treated as aliases and collide.
> While the spelling of pathnames in filesystem events depends upon the underlying filesystem, such as APFS, HFS+ or FAT32, the OS enforces such collisions regardless of filesystem.
>
> Teach the daemon to always report the NFC spelling and to report the NFD spelling when stored in that format on the disk.
>
> This is slightly more general than "`core.precomposeUnicode`".